# Save values to file(e.g yml) in java

Tags: java, file, yaml

First of all this might be a dumb question and I searched for some days but didn't find an answer. So if there is an existing answer concerning my question, I would be grateful for a link.

I don't know if anyone of you ever coded Spigot, Paper or Bukkit, but there was a class called *YamlConfiguration* which had the following methods:

```
public FileConfiguration cfg = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(file);
cfg.set(path.path2, "hello");
cfg.getInt/String/...(path.path2); (which obviously returns "hello")
cfg.save(file);
```

The produced file then looks like this:

```
path:
    path2: "hello"
```

So you could basically save any value in those files and reuse them even if your program has been restarted.
I know have moved forward from Spigot/Paper to native Java and I'm missing something like that Yaml-thing. The only thing I found was a kind of a config file, where every time the whole file is overwritten, when I try to add values.

Can you show me a proper way of saving values to a file? (would be nice without libraries)

Comment: Please, do NOT use images for textual information. Instead, **paste the text** into the question post. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm missing sth like that Yaml-thing

[SnakeYAML](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/src/master/) should have you covered. Without knowing anything about your use-case, it makes no sense to discuss its usage here since its documentation already does cover the general topics.

> The only thing I found was a kind of a config file, where everytime the whole file is overwritten, when I try to add values.

Saving as YAML will always overwrite the complete file as well. Serialization does not really work with append-only. (*Serialization* is the term to search for when you want functionality like this, by the way.)

If you mean that previous values were deleted, that probably was because you didn't load the file's content before or some other coding error, but since you don't show your code, we can only speculate.

> Can you show me a proper way of saving values to a file?

People will have quite different opinions on what would be a *proper* way and therefore it is not a good question to ask here. It also heavily depends on your use-case.

> would be nice without libraries

So you're basically saying „previously I used a library which had a nice feature but I want to have that feature without using a library“. This stance won't get you far in today's increasingly modular software world.

For example, [JAXB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding) which offers (de)serialization from/to XML was previously part of Java SE, but has been removed as of Java SE 11 and is a separate library now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try my best with SnakeYAML and if that won't work, i'll come back to here.